# Why can't I see or share replays in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I open up my defense messages and attack messages, replays are not available, even my most recent attacks. Any help?

Comment: I've noticed this a few times, notably after a game update or a new feature was added. Sometimes they just appear back again. Not sure if anyone outside of the game company can really answer this.

Comment: Thanks! Just was worried that I couldn't see my replays.

Comment: @Sparow I deleted my comment above and just converted this to an answer for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replays are usually lost or set to unavailable after there is a update or maintenance window.

Source: Personal experience

Comment: Also, only 5 Normal Defence Replays and Attack Replays are saved